# Setup nginx as proxy server for kestrel (ASP.Net Core)

Tags: nginx, centos-7

I am trying to setup an ASP.NET Core Environment to host my application but I am having trouble with the nginx webserver. When I try to connect to my domain I get `502 Bad Gateway`. Nginx should just run as proxy server for kestrel.

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1) ist a link to the guide which I am following. The config is pretty much the config that is suggested by microsoft I just changed the variables that are different for each environment.

The line that is a problem is `http://aspdotnethost;` at the end of the nginx.conf configuration. When I comment it out I am getting redirected to the default www location.

So how does the line actually work and how can I manage it to properly redirect to localhost:5000 ?

/etc/nginx/proxy.conf

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
    server_tokens off;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 29; # Adjust to the lowest possible value that makes sense for your use case.
    client_body_timeout 10; client_header_timeout 10; send_timeout 10;

    upstream aspdotnethost {
        server localhost:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen *:80;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen *:443    ssl;
        server_name     example.com *.example.com;

        #Redirects all traffic
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://aspdotnethost;
            limit_req   zone=one burst=10;
        }
    }

}
```

Nginx config check:

```
[root@rs-zap353479-1 patrick]# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

When I type in `curl http://localhost:5000` then I get the html document returned. So that component should be finde in my eyes.

Comment: What happens if you run `curl 'http://aspdotnethost'`on the CentOS host?

Comment: `Name or service not known` so what should I do that the name or service is known?

Comment: edit `/etc/hosts` to include the IP of your ASP host under the name of `aspdotnethost` (as you have called it in your nginx configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Like Eugen Rieck posted as comment I had to add an alias to `/etc/hosts`.

As additional step I have to specify the `proxy_temp_path` in the `proxy.conf`, create that path and chown it to the user which is nginx running under (in my case `nginx`).